# How to get started with ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I am beginner to ExtJS technology. I wish to learn it.

But, how should I start it ?

1. Sencha's price is too high to buy ?
2. Is Sencha's tutorial available for free ?
3. Is ExtJS needs to be run in a special IDE ?

Thank you

Comment: "Sencha's price is too high to buy ?" How is that relevant to learning Ext JS?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find several guides accessible from the API docs main page: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/

There are books you can buy, though I don't if any of them covers Ext4. Note that transitioning from Ext3 to Ext4 is rather easy and straightforward (I wouldn't know about migrating an existing codebase).

There is no IDE requirement, ExtJS is straight JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're saying still holds for ExtJS4. The [learning center](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/getting_started) has improved significantly.

Comment: There is no extjs designer for v4 as of july2011, but this should change in weeks/months.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I didn't realize there were a bunch of new guides accessible from the new docs, so I guess I was wrong. I've edited my answer. The information on the main Sencha site is still quite out of date (see: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorials).

Comment: Now with new overwiew page: http://www.sencha.com/blog/introducing-our-new-learning-center/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Its free using the gpl terms, download it and toy with the examples. Anything you would make money from would be able to easily pay for the cost of the kit.